# How to get Object / Any from Bundle in API 33 Android?

Tags: android

As you can see

```
val status = bundle?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status
```

`get()` is deprecated.

If I see, inner implementation of `get()`

```
/**
     * Returns the entry with the given key as an object.
     *
     * @param key a String key
     * @return an Object, or null
     *
     * @deprecated Use the type-safe specific APIs depending on the type of the item to be
     *      retrieved, eg. {@link #getString(String)}.
     */
    @Deprecated
    @Nullable
    public Object get(String key) {
        unparcel();
        return getValue(key);
    }
```

But the problem is, I need to receive Custom model class object, not any String. But in implementation they suggest only for getString() and suggestion are for primitive types!

No proper solution getting from Google and Stack Overflow!